# bootstrap panel does not clip ckeditor generated table in heroku

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I have a blogging platform where bloggers use ckeditor to create posts. When a user creates a body containing a table, and I show the body inside a bootstrap panel within a col-md-3, the table overflows beyond the panel. So, I added a wrapper with class clipped, and set the style to overflow:hidden. It seems to work in dev. See http://www.bootply.com/rdM60mFcKL

But when I deploy it to production, the table still overflows out beyond the containing panel-body.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">  
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class='clipped'>
        <div class="panel panel-warning">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px"> 
                <tbody><tr> 
                  <td>Foo</td> 
                  <td>Bar</td> 
                  <td>Baz</td> 
                </tr> 
            </tbody></table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>          
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clipped, .clipped .panel, .clipped .panel-heading, .clipped .panel-body, .clipped .panel-footer, .clipped table  {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The only thing I can think of is that ckeditor has some styles on its content that are overriding the behavior.

Comment: I think I found the problem - I forgot to precompile the assets and upload after adding the clipped class css :-)